# Are there some memory leaks in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    void p() const { std::cout << "B::p\n"; }
    void q() const { std::cout << "B::q\n"; }

    int b;
};

class D : public B { 
public:
    D() {}

    virtual void p() const { std::cout << "D::p\n"; }
    virtual void q() const { std::cout << "D::q\n"; }

    int d;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    B b;
    D d;

    B* pb = new B;
    B* pd = new D;
    D* pd2 = new D;

    b.p(); b.q();
    d.p(); d.q();

    pb->p(); pb->q();
    pd->p(); pd->q();
    pd2->p(); pd2->q();

    delete pb;
    delete pd;
    delete pd2;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like that there is a memory leak in `delete pd`. I guess that `pd` is not a pointer to `D`, so when I `delete` it, it doesn't call the destructor of `D`, but the desctructor of `B`. However, I don't know the exact reason. Who could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Provide `virtual` destructor functions to get `D`'s destructor called.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to try and delete a derived object via a base class pointer, if the destructor is not virtual

Answer (score 3):

There may well be memory leaks in your code.   But equally, there may not be.

As noted in comments, this sequence

```
B* pd = new D;
delete pd;
```

in your code  (irrespective of all the other code you have provided) gives undefined behaviour, since `B` does not have a `virtual` destructor.

When behaviour is undefined, anything can happen, including a memory leak or anything else you might or might not imagine.

If you declare a `virtual` destructor for `B`, and define it so it does does not leak memory (e.g. `virtual ~B() {}`) then your code will have well-defined behaviour.   All objects you have created with operator `new` are correctly destroyed with operator `delete`, so - if `B` has a virtual destructor - none of them contribute to a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that destructor of D is not getting called? Your sample code does not even have a destructor. In fact, it wouldn't call destructor of D as pointed in the comments. Not having a virtual destructor in a base class is not good.

Try following sample,

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() { std::cout << "B::dtor\n"; }
    void p() const { std::cout << "B::p\n"; }
    void q() const { std::cout << "B::q\n"; }

    int b;
};

class D : public B {
public:
    D() {}
    virtual ~D() { std::cout << "D::dtor\n"; }

    virtual void p() const { std::cout << "D::p\n"; }
    virtual void q() const { std::cout << "D::q\n"; }

    int d;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    B b;
    D d;

    B* pb = new B;
    B* pd = new D;
    D* pd2 = new D;

    b.p(); b.q();
    d.p(); d.q();

    pb->p(); pb->q();
    pd->p(); pd->q();
    pd2->p(); pd2->q();

    delete pb;
    delete pd;
    delete pd2;

    return 0;
}
```

To your question, there is a leak in your implementation, as pd gets deleted probable memory cleaning written in dtor of D wouldn't be invoked.

Answer (score -1):

```
B* pb = new B;
//B::B()

B* pd = new D;
//B::B()   <-- constructor called
//D::D()   <-- constructor called

D* pd2 = new D;
//B::B()
//D::D()

....
pd->p(); pd->q();
//B::p
//B::q
....

delete pb;
//~B::B()

delete pd;
//~B::B()  <-- leaks here

delete pd2;
//~D::D()
//~B::B()
```

You should use the keyword "virtual" for the destructor of class B:

```
private:
virtual ~B() {}
```

Comment: Contrary to your comment, the `delete pd` statement has undefined behaviour.  It does not necessarily call only `B::~B()`, nor does it necessarily leak memory (which is something different from calling or not calling a destructor).     Also, making `B`s destructor private will prevent creating any instances of `B` or `D` (unless that happens in a member function or friend of `B`).

Comment: As `pd->p();` --> `B::p`, `pd->q();` --> `B::q`. we also have `delete pd;` --> `~B::B()`. I think the problem is that the destructor function of D is not called.

Comment: @Peter: It is wrong to use "private" keyword. Thank you for your suggestions.